# 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' when calling Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am receiving this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

and also:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

when running this method, and the error is occurring on the `CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instantiationString), parameters)` call:

```
public static Report instantiateReport(ReportInfo reportInfo)
{
    string instantiationString;
    Report reportToReturn;
    ReportInfo[] parameters = new ReportInfo[1];
    parameters[0] = reportInfo;

    instantiationString = reportInfo.Report.InstantiationPath;
    reportToReturn = (Report)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instantiationString), parameters);

    return reportToReturn;
}
```

`ReportInfo` is just a custom class that contains variables that help me build the report that I am trying to instantiate and when I investigate it, everything is completely fine. The `instantiationString` just helps me understand which report is trying to be created at the call and that way I can use the Type.GetType() method. I really have no idea what kind of error this is or what could be going wrong. I researched it a bit but didn't receive any helpful answer so any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** After looking at the inner exception I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` message. This is strange because neither the `ReportInfo` or the `GetType()` methods have a null reference. Say one of the variables within `ReportInfo` was null, could that cause an issue? It shouldn't right?

**FIXED** After delving into the stack trace of the inner exception I found that there was some conflicting code causing issues elsewhere. Problem solved.

Comment: Have you tried checking out what the `InnerException` property was on the `TargetInvocation` exception you are getting ? It may contain more info on what's going on. Also, can you give us some sample input that would be used for the `instantiationString` ?

Comment: My guess is that something goes wrong in the `ReportInfo` constructor. If it's you own class, try putting a breakpoint in the actual constructor you are supposed to be targeting, see if it's the right one that is being called and what exactly is happenning during the instanciation process.